# How to merge a list of list of list as one?

Tags: python, list

If I have 2 liist of list of list:

```
A = [ [[2,3],[3,4]] ] 

B = [ [[5,6],[7,3],[3,1]],
      [[2,5],[3,2],[4,2]],
      [[2,1],[2,3],[3,1]] ]
```

and I want to merge A into B.So the first list of list of A is in the first list of list of B and so on.

Output:

```
 C = [ [[5,6],[7,3],[3,1],[2,3],[3,4]],
       [[2,5],[3,2],[4,2]],
       [[2,1],[2,3],[3,1]] ]
```

I tried using zip(A,B) but they are put in tuples and list so it's really confusing?

Comment: Those are not two lists of lists, they are lists of lists of lists. Is that what you want? Also, your example output makes no sense from the input. You include all of A at the end of the first list of B, only one value in the second, and none in the third. Do you want all of A at the end of the first result list and remove one item from the front of A until A is exhausted? Please explain more fully in words.

Comment: Yes the output shd be a list of list.Sorry I made a mistake in the output.Since length A is only 1 I include the firat list of list of A in the first list of list in B.But if it's 2 then I include the second list of list of A in sexond list of list of B as well

Comment: Is there a reason you are making multiple accounts and asking similar questions? https://stackoverflow.com/users/8682070/sook-yee-lim .  Please do your own homework assignments.

Comment: Hello Lim, mind marking the correct answer as correct? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would work:

```
>>> A=[ [ [2,3],[3,4] ] ]
>>> B=[ [ [ [5,6],[7,3],[3,1]],[ [2,5],[3,2],[4,2] ],[ [2,1],[2,3],[3,1]]]]
>>> B[0][0] += A[0]
>>> B
[[[[5, 6], [7, 3], [3, 1], [2, 3], [3, 4]], [[2, 5], [3, 2], [4, 2]], [[2, 1], [2, 3], [3, 1]]]]
```

Edited answer.

Comment: Hi I've made a mistake with the output and have edited it. But what I meant is that thw first list of list in A shd be merged with the first list of list in B.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a oneliner but it solves your problem:

```
def my_list_merge(A,B):
    """ Merge the elements from A into B """
    C = []
    for i in range(len(A)):
        C += [B[i]+A[i]]
    C += B[i+1:]
    return C
```

So to use this method on some easier to read data:

```
>>> A = [ [[4,4]] ]
>>> B = [ [[1,1],[1,1]],
          [[2,2],[2,2]],
          [[3,3],[3,3]] ]
>>> my_list_merge(A,B)
 [ [[1, 1], [1, 1], [4, 4]],
   [[2, 2], [2, 2]],
   [[3, 3], [3, 3]] ]
```

And to show it scales (s.t. len(A) <= len(B))

```
>>> A = [ [[4,4],[4,4]] ]
>>> B = [ [[1,1],[1,1],[1,1]], 
          [[2,2],[2,2],[2,2]], 
          [[3,3],[3,3],[3,3]] ]
>>> my_list_merge(A,B)
[[[1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1], [4, 4], [4, 4]],
 [[2, 2], [2, 2], [2, 2], [5, 5], [5, 5]],
 [[3, 3], [3, 3], [3, 3]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

```
A = [ [ [2,3],[3,4] ] ]

B = [ [ [5,6],[7,3],[3,1]],[ [2,5],[3,2],[4,2] ],[ [2,1],[2,3],[3,1]]]

C = [B[0] + A[0], B[1], B[2]]

print(C)
```

It prints:

```
[[[5, 6], [7, 3], [3, 1], [2, 3], [3, 4]], [[2, 5], [3, 2], [4, 2]], [[2, 1], [2, 3], [3, 1]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try with A.append(B), it gives you added list.